# What datatype in Snowflake works for image data

Tags: image, sqldatatypes

I need to store data that is in the SQL Server Image datatype into Snowflake. Is there a specific datatype that will work or does Variant cover it?

Answer (score 5):

In snowflake you will not be able to store image data directly. What you can do is to load the image files on S3 object store(or Azure Blob Store or GCS) and store the metadata of the image in Snowflake so that the image can be analyzed with other data in your data warehouse.